# JS |Xss defence question

Tags: javascript, cookies, xss

I have a website where users can post comments.
I want to know that if they find an xss hole, if they can still get the cookie data although it's httpOnly with some kind of XHTTPrequest, Ajax call or something.
Is it possible?

Comment: you can always NOT write your cookies in plain text, so even then the information won't be of any use to the attacker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP-only cookies cannot be retrieved by JavaScript. Hence ["HTTP-only"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie).

Comment: In theory, yes, but there have been attacks which obtained them. See for example http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=341 or https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Tracing

Comment: Source dates: 2003 and 2009. We're almost living in 2012. All of the current, modern browsers are correctly implementing `httpOnly` cookies.

Comment: But Can't I use some kind of Ajx request to get the headers containing the cookie values?

Comment: Http-only cookies are ONLY visible to the browser's engine, which handles the HTPT request. These are not visible to the JavaScript engine. How often should I rephrase that?

Comment: @Rob W: those weren't browser bugs though - the cookies were only being sent over HTTP. The bugs were cased by accidental interactions with another feature in a way that hadn't been predicted.

Comment: If you're really afraid of Cross-site tracing, read [this article](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/867593). That document describes how to disable this specific feature.

Comment: If you have XSS the attacker can do anything on behalf of the user, without stealing the cookie. Javascript can open other pages, read data, perform actions etc. Have a look at BeEF to get a sense of all the horrible things XSS flaws can be used to perform (deliver browser exploits etc.)